# How to delete a specific document from azure search index?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-python-sdk

I have a specific number of documents from the azure search index to be deleted and I need a solution in python for the same.
I created an index in azure search already and the format of the index is given below

```
> {
>     "@odata.context": "https://{name}.search.windows.net/indexes({'index name'})/$metadata#docs(*)",
>     "value": [
>         {
>             "@search.score": ,
>             "content": "",
>             "metadata_storage_name": "",
>             "metadata_storage_path": "",
>             "metadata_storage_file_extension": "",}]}
```

**metadata_storage_path** is the unique key for each document in azure search index.

I got 2 ways to go about the problem using azure-python SDK and python request module but both the  methods are throwing me an error which is listed below.

**method - 1 (using python request module)**

I got the reference from azure documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents

```
import json
import requests
api_key = "B346FEAB56E6D5*******"
headers = {
  'api-key': f'{api_key}',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
doc_idx = "Index name"
doc_url = f"https://{name}.search.windows.net/indexes/{doc_idx}-index/docs/search?api-version=2020-06-30-Preview"

payload = json.dumps({

"@search.action": "delete",
"key_field_name":({"metadata_storage_path": "aHR0cHM6Ly9mc2NvZ******"})
},
)
response = json.loads(requests.request("POST", doc_url, headers=headers, data=payload).text)
print(response)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
{'error': {'code': '',
  'message': "The request is invalid.## Heading ## Details: parameters : The parameter 'key_field_name' in the request payload is not a valid parameter for the operation 'search'.\r\n"}}
```

I also tried manipulating the code but I am not able to make it work please let me know weather i am making some mistake in the code or is there some issues with the python request module and azure search.

**Method - 2 (using azure python SDK)**

I got the Reference from azure documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.searchclient?view=azure-python

I tried to delete one document inside the azure search index with azure python SDK and the code is given below.

```
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient

key = AzureKeyCredential('B346FEAB******')
doc_idx = "index name"
service_endpoint  = f"https://{name}.search.windows.net/indexes/{doc_idx}-index/docs/search?api-version=2020-06-30-Preview"
search_client = SearchClient(service_endpoint, doc_idx , key,)

# result = search_client.delete_documents(documents=[DOCUMENT])

result = search_client.delete_documents(documents=[{"metadata_storage_name": "XYZ.jpg"}])

print("deletion of  document succeeded: {}".format(result[0].succeeded))
```

I am getting the following error.

```
ResourceNotFoundError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-88beecc15663> in <module>
     13 # result = search_client.upload_documents(documents=[DOCUMENT])
     14 
---> 15 result = search_client.delete_documents(documents=[{"metadata_storage_name": "XYZ.jpg"}])----------------------------------------------

ResourceNotFoundError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Not Found'
```

I also tried using metadata_storage_path instead of metadata_storage_name and I got the same error.

please check the code and let me know where I am making mistake and also if there is any other method for deleting a specific document in azure search index.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a variable for *name*.

```
service_endpoint  = f"https://{name}.search.windows.net/indexes/{doc_idx}-index/docs/search?api-version=2020-06-30-Preview"
```

Becomes

```
https://.search.windows.net/indexes/Index%20name-index/docs/search?api-version=2020-06-30-Preview
```

Comment: I have defined it, due to security reasons i have not given it here.

Comment: Ok. It would be easier to help you if you included the variable but with dummy replacements for the sensitive values. I believe the error message is accurate. The resource does not exist because either the name, index or id you specified is incorrect.

Comment: Tip: Download Postman and get an example working there. Once it is working you can click a button to get Postman to generate fully working code for you. It supports a large number of programming languages aswell.